# Handler not removing callbacks from removeCallbacksAndMessages() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-handler

When a user opens a fragment, I need to call service after 30 seconds. So, I executes the following code.

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000); 

runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       fetchData(true);
    }
};
```

But I need to stop this handler when a user leaves the fragment, so I execute following code in all possible pause blocks, but the issue is that it keeps hitting the service, if I go to other fragment or put an application in history.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(handler!=null) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(handler !=null){
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if(handler !=null){
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

I need to know how to cancel the handler.

Comment: How did you add fragment in the activity? which of the following method you used :addToBackStack(name) or replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag) or add(containerViewId, fragment, tag);

Comment: @SultanMahmud I used `replace`

Comment: In onResume method add the handler code when fragment is visible like
if ( this.isVisible()) {
 // add handler code
}

Comment: Can you show your full fragment code?

Answer (score 0):

> **I need to know how to cancel the handler**

There is nothing like Start or Stop or Cancel for Handler. It's job is to just post the Runnables and Messages to the Thread Queue.

you have already written `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` to remove the callBacks you started before. I think that's enough for you.

Comment: but it keeps executing the handler code, even when fragment is on pause or stopped state.